# What buildings should I place inside a wall?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I now have the ability to build walls, and they seem to be of strategic importance whenever I play against the computer.  I've yet to be attacked by any other players, but I feel that is coming soon and I'd like to minimize my losses.  I don't have enough wall to fully enclose my camp, so I need to decide what goes inside and what goes out.  Which buildings should I prioritize?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm still experimenting with this, and I believe there are many strategies - but here's what I know so far.

1. **Your Town Hall***.  This is pretty straight forward, when keep trophies is your goal - losing it means automatic defeat.  Consider upgraded walls around it.
2. **Your collectors and storage tanks**.  Attackers will target these, as it is one of the key objectives of attacking - to steal resources.
3. **Your defenses**.  Attackers will target these in order to stop losing troops, and they should be close to your Town Hall/collectors/storage anyway.

* Do note that if resource farming is your goal, you may be better served leaving your Town Hall exposed in order to solicit cheap shields, and distract focus from your storage tanks.

By exclusion, this means that your Barracks, Army Camp, Laboratory, Builder's Hut etc are not essential to be inside the wall.  They still count towards your 50% building mark, which can result in a loss - so fit them when you can.  They also serve as a good distraction for dumber units like barbarians, so keep that in mind.  I have found that savvy players will place certain buildings like builders huts way away from the rest of their camp, to force attack units to hoof it.  This can cost attackers valuable time, and may even save you from defeat when your defenses are exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

Clan Castle, so the enemy would have trouble luring the troops out of it. Town Hall since if destroyed, you'll lose. Storages, so the enemy won't steal the loot. Defences, to protect the storages and town hall. And last but not least, barbarian king and archer queen.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting your townhall inside walls, defences, or other important buildings.

If you are a farmer and you do not care for trophies put your storages and defences inside walls and leave your townhall open to attack, that way when you get raided they might drop 5 archers or so, get your townhall, and leave giving you  a free 16 hour shield to protect your recourses. 
If you are gathering trophies or a trophy base, you would have your townhall and defences protected. You would probably put gold storages, elixir storages, mines, and collectors on the outside of the base.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you keep your defences inside the walls, and splash damage defences toward the centre. Keep them spread out to get good coverage and keep them in sperate compartments.

If you care about trophies, keep your town hall inside your walls, if you don't, chuck it out. This has various benefits including getting a shield without losing many resources and that the town hall can be an awkward shape to fit inside your walls.

Your storages should be centralised for maximum protection.

If you are active, it should be fine to leave your collectors outside your base, but remember to keep them close to your walls.

Answer (score 0):

I put my TH and storage buildings, as well as my defenses, inside my walls. I am TH5 on one account and TH6 on my other one.

Answer (score -2):

Put as many defences as possible in your walls enimies will try to destroy them and if they can't they will be KILLED